Oracle Apex - usage of html tags in calendar
I worked with html tags in the legacy Apex calendars for many years (APEX5 and below) to create some formatting and links within then calendar-view.
Since the new CSS calender I could not find a way to use any kind of html-Tags but I would need to make some formatting and insert links to different other pages with the -Tag (from one Calender I usualy jump to many different pages depending on the kind of entry that is shown)
Code is something like that (just an example to see my usage of html tags). The Tags are removed in the new calendar and I cant find a way to use them like I did in the legacy calendar
select 
    t.startdate_dt
  , t.enddate_dt
  , '<b>' || t.responsibility || '</b><br><br>' ||
    t.customer_name || '<br>' ||
    t.customer_phone || '<br>' ||
    '<a href="' || t.my_generated_link || '">Link</a>' as calendar_text
from t_mytasks t

I know about the ways to highlight an full calendar entry with CSS classes apex-cal-red, apex-cal-cyan, etc ... but thats by far noch enough for my needs and so I cannot update any of my old legacy-calendars and I am stuck when trying to make changes to the formatting in a new calender.
tried to use tags within the code, looked for ways to deactivate the escaping-function, looked for function to deactivate the escape function within the sql statement - just didn't find a way
Thanks a lot for your help!
Jürgen

I would post this in the official oracle APEX forum: https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/domain/dev-community/category/apex

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

thanks for your comments, I put some lines of code there to show my usage of the calendar. The tags always get escaped (so I see  or  in the calendar - in the apex forum I also just found the same question but no solution
